# Shared ownership/Fair payout

Tags: mortgage

In a house with 3 shared ownership, one moves out and the other assumes payment. How do we determine a fair payment amount to the person that moved out? The 2 were a married couple who put down 50% of down payment and the third party put the other 50% down payment. In a matter of 2 years the third party moves out. The house is being sold for $150k more than what the initial cost of the house was. Is there some type of formula to figure out a fair split?

Comment: During the 2 years were mortgage payments and other costs split evenly, or did the married couple pay 2/3 of those?

Comment: If the married couple paid half and the mortgage payments were split in half then the married couple will proabably be treated as one party, and the profits should be split in half.  Are all three properties on the deed?  The split will probably need to be decided in order to sell the house.

Comment: the mortgage was split 50% for the third party and the married couple 50%. The third party moved after 2 years and the married couple paid the mortgage for 8yrs total.

Comment: Unfortunately, fair is whatever everyone involved agrees is fair.  You all probably should have made an agreement up front, but definitely make an agreement before you sell.  People's opinion of how fair their position is typically changes over time, especially when/if actual money differs from expected money in events like a potential sale.

Comment: What about an agreement when 3rd party moved out and how much rent is due to them? If such purchases are made and no agreement has been made at any time during the 8 years then no wonder there is a mess now. No forward thinking at all - followed by disputes at the end !

Comment: Unfortunately, without more information and without an agreement no one on the internet can work out appropriate calculations for you.

Comment: And the law might say... you each put down 50% so you're each equal co-owners.

Comment: Why do people assume it's a messy situation? It may well be, but OP is simply asking for a fair method of calculation.

Comment: The OP is asking for a formula to figure out a fair spit but has not provided enough information to do so. It is like saying here is your formula: a + b + c + d + ? x #, where a and b are known but c and d are not known and ? and # - well we don't even know whether to include them or not.

Comment: @j.red - is this an exam question? If not, which party are you?

Answer (score 1):

Without any other sort of agreement in place, they own the amount of equity that they did when they first purchased the house, according to how much of the downpayment they spent. Changing the amount paid on the mortgage changes nothing, the lender is only concerned that it gets paid, but doesn't care who pays it.

If all parties agree it can be fair to make adjustments in equity based on the amount paid towards the mortgage, but that should be agreed on in advance. The fairest agreement would still end up being approximately 50% for the couple and 50% for the third party, because even though the couple was paying the whole mortgage for several years, that is effectively equivalent to them paying half the mortgage and the other half in rent to the 3rd party (who then forwards that towards the mortgage). If it was a standard mortgage and the payments were approximately equal to what the house could rent for, the 3rd party getting 50% is as fair as it gets.

If the house could be expected to rent for significantly more than the mortgage payment in its market (on average throughout the years the 3rd party didn't live there) it would be fair for the 3rd party to receive a bit more than 50% since a little more than half that mortgage payment can be thought of as having been forwarded through the 3rd party.

If the house could only be expected to rent for significantly less than the mortgage payment (again, on average throughout the years the 3rd party didn't live there) it would be fair for the 3rd party to receive a bit less than 50%.

Either way, 50% for the couple, 50% for the 3rd party, is pretty close to a fair situation. Remember though, what's fair doesn't matter, it's what was agreed upon that matters (see paragraph 1).

Comment: *that is effectively equivalent to them paying half the mortgage and the other half in rent to the 3rd party (who then forwards that towards the mortgage)*  Interesting POV

Comment: Regarding the first paragraph, wouldn't the lender be equally unconcerned (and uninvolved) in the disposition of any gain after the loan is paid off?

Comment: @chepner Yes, obviously. That's none of the lender's business.

Comment: This answer is the most correct so I don't know why it has been downvoted. In fact if there is no agreement then by law each party is owed whatever percentage ownership is on the title deed. If this is 50% then each party is owed 50% of the proceeds at sale.

Comment: In fact, in Australia, tax law specifies that you will pay tax on any proceeds (income or capital gains) based on the ownership percentage in the title deed, no matter who actually makes the payment. This might be similar in other countries?

Answer (score -5):

The couple payed 50% of the mortgage for 25% of the time of ownership, and 100% of the mortgage for 75% of the time.  Thus, **morally**, they should get `50% * 25% + 100% * 75% = 87.5%` of the profit.

But that might not be what the law says.

EDIT: I'd be interested to know why it was down-voted.

Comment: I didn't vote you down, but as the married couple where living there and the third person wasn't, don't they then owe the third person rent during that period. So paying the full mortgage might be in place of paying rent. So considering this your calculation makes no sense.

Comment: @Victor, there's no indication anyone was paying rent, and the word rent isn't raised until you mention it.  In a perfect world a non-resident owner would probably request some sort of use rent, but when the remaining tenants of the property are also owners and you're relinquished of your duty to pay toward the mortgage it stands to reason no rent was expected or paid.  Your comments would probably be more effective if directed at the person who ask the question, though I agree the calculation is more complicated than a ratio of mortgage contributions.

Comment: No, you have made your calculations based on no rent being due to the 3rd party who moved out and the couple enjoyed living there for another 6 years. They still own 50% of the property as would be shown on the deed, and as the couple are living there and 3rd party isn't, they should be owed rent during those 6 years - something you have totally ignored in your incorrect calculations.

Comment: What rent?  For 6 years, they put 100% of the equity in the house; ergo they should get 100% of the profit from that 6 years of value increase.  If the 3rd party wanted a bigger share of the pie, he should have been putting equity into the house also.

Comment: @RonJohn, for the 6 years one party paid 100% of the mortgage their equity allocation should not be 100% because it ignores the loss of utility of the property of the other owner.  As an example, the non-resident, non-paying owner should get maybe 10% of the equity allocation over that time period for consideration of their loss of utility of the property.  The issue here is property has more costs and expenses than payment of the loan and we're not privy to any agreements or any repairs.  A simple mortgage payment ratio calculation split is too simplified.

Comment: @RonJohn - so you don't think the 3rd party was due any rent whilst not living there, you have made no allowance for it so your calculation is incorrect.

Comment: I don't see a lack of utility when there's no additional expense. Still benefiting from increased equity, just at a decreased rate.

Comment: @quid the Third Party didn't **lose** utility, he(?) *voluntarily relinquished it* by moving out and not putting any money into the house ( taxes, upkeep, etc).

Comment: "so you don't think the 3rd party was due any rent".  Correct, because **the 3rd party didn't do anything**.

Comment: @RonJohn - yes they did, they paid a 50% deposit and paid 50% of expenses whilst living there for 2 years - so if not living there they are due compensation (rent) for allowing someone else to live there. As I said without an agreement you cannot make any calculation and the one you have made is very simplistic and incorrect.

Comment: "yes they did, they paid a 50% deposit and paid 50% of expenses whilst living there for 2 years"  Right.  So the 3P deserves 50% of the increase in home value **for the two years he lived there, paying 50% of the mortgage**.

Comment: @RonJohn - and they are also due 50% rent for period they were not living there which looks to not have been paid. So maybe the couple paying the full mortgage is compenation for the 3rd party not getting any rent. Without an agreement and more information we know nothing of this so we cannot make any realistic calculations.

Comment: @Victor no, I (and I believe Hart CO) think you are completely and fundamentally wrong about this.

Comment: @RonJohn, your answer indicates that a 50% owner should receive no consideration for their ownership, over the 6 years they were not residents.  Victor and I disagree with you.  It could very well be that everyone involved is comfortable with the non-resident owner receiving $0 consideration for their ownership of the home during the time they did not contribute to the mortgage, but I don't think that is defacto "fair."  I don't think this is a fair rate of equity dilution.

Comment: @quid that's what judges (and black letter law) are for...

Comment: I agree that lawyers will probably get involved.  If I was the non-resident owner and my equity position was being diluted from 50% to 12% I'd definitely not go quietly in to the night.

Comment: Your 50% share of the equity was reduced every time you didn't pay 50% of the mortgage.

Comment: @RonJohn, I disagree because the couple that retained residency of the home did not pay any consideration to the other owner who did was not a resident.  They should have been paying some sort of rent/consideration to the non-resident owner that would be represented in the equity ratio, or they should have bought the other owner out entirely, or the three of them should have found a tenant to pay rent.  The non-resident is being diluted too dramatically.  Reducing the 50% is fair but 0% consideration over the 6 years is not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58820/discussion-between-ronjohn-and-quid).